# Symfony generator.yml link method

Tags: symfony1, admin-generator

How do I specify the method of an action (similar to _delete):

```
generator:
  config:
    list:
      object_actions:
        myaction: {label: Label, action: myaction, method: post}
```

This ignores my method setting and renders a get link:

```
<a href="/backend/myaction/1">Label</a>
```

Whereas I want it to a "post" link, similar to _delete (with onclick attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your using Propel.

If you check the generator code, specifically on: generator > theme_name > template > template > _list_td_actions.php, there you'll find a pice of code like:

```
<?php else: ?>
    <li class="sf_admin_action_<?php echo $params['class_suffix'] ?>">
      <?php echo $this->addCredentialCondition($this->getLinkToAction($name, $params, true), $params) ?>

    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That's the code thats being executed when you define a custom object action like the one you described. Check $params and you may find a solution to your needs ( i think that probably you could define something like the onclick attribute value).

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to have a confirmation message than probably the best way is:

```
generator:
  config:
    list:
      object_actions:
        myaction: {label: Label, action: myaction, confirm: "Are your sure?", params: {onclick: 'alert("Bu!");'} }
```

Additional parameters to link_to can be passed with 'params' option (notice 'onclick' in the example above).

Comment: Thank you! But I still can't get it to work. I've created a linkToMyaction method, but it is simply ignored. There is no reference to it in list_td_action partial (compared to standard actions). It works if I manually override list_td_action partial and call <?php echo $helper->linkToMyaction... ?> from there. Am i missing something?

Comment: linkToMyaction() can be only used with object actions on the form and not on the list. Sorry for misleading you. I fixed my reply.

Comment: Well, I guess I do have to override list_td_action partial then.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will be useful

```
generator:
  config:
    list:
      object_actions:
        myaction:{ params: { onclick : "if(confirm('Are you sure?')){return true;}else{return false;}" } }
```

Comment: You meant `onclick : "return confirm('Are you sure?')"`